# sudo: unable to resolve host slave-node: Name or service not known when need to install skaffold on ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, devops, skaffold

i want to use the skaffold in ubuntu 20 . i using this command for install :

```
curl -Lo skaffold https://storage.googleapis.com/skaffold/builds/latest/skaffold-linux-amd64 && \
sudo install skaffold /usr/local/bin/
```

and it complete downloaded but after complete download it show me this message :

```
sudo: unable to resolve host slave-node: Name or service not known
```

> i installed the kubernetes in my ubuntu

this is my `skaffold.yaml` in my project :

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v0.25.0
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: stephengrider/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

and when i run this command it show me this message :

```
parsing skaffold config: unknown api version: "skaffold/v0.25.0"
```

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong API version.

Look at the skaffold.yaml [reference page](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/) - you can see there proper `apiVersion` examples:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta10 
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta9
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha1
etc
```

Even if you use [Skaffold v0.25.0 Release - 3/15/2019](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/releases/tag/v0.25.0), there is a note that fix your problem.

> Note: This release comes with a new config version v1beta7. To upgrade
> your skaffold.yaml, use skaffold fix. If you don't upgrade, skaffold
> will auto-upgrade in memory as best it can, and print a warning
> message.

So using `apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta7` should help